# How to resolve my fatal error while trying to migrate an existing site to Platform.sh?

Tags: 7, migrations

I am new to `Platform.sh` and I am trying to migrate an existing site to Platform.sh, using the [Platform.sh documentation](https://docs.platform.sh/toolstacks/php/drupal/migrate-existing-site/).

I have successfully imported the code base, the database, and the files. I tried to "`Rebuild the site registry`" and execute the following command:

> $ php ../tmp/registry_rebuild/registry_rebuild.php

But it resulted in an error like so:

> web@x6l3bau6sowvu-master--php:~/public$ php
> ../tmp/registry_rebuild/registry_rebuild.php
>
> DRUPAL_ROOT is /app/public/sites/default/files.
>
> Bootstrapping to DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_SESSION
>
> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function db_query() in
> /app/public/sites/default/files/includes/cache.inc on line 348
>
> Fatal error: Call to undefined function db_query() in
> /app/public/sites/default/files/includes/cache.inc on line 348
>
> web@x6l3bau6sowvu-master--php:~/public$

I do not understand what this means. Can anyone tell me what is wrong, and how can I solve this issue?